# Writing jenkins plugin: where is the documentation?

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins, jenkins

On my current project we're using Jenkins to monitor our builds. Now they want me to write a Jenkins plugin to add some more monitoring parameters.

I've taken a look at how the status monitor plugin works, and I can't figure some things out. I've tried to look for documentation for writing a plugin, but that seems to be sorely lacking. (the site only mentions how to generate the base project, and refers to a tutorial that's not that informative)

What I'm trying to do is just add some options to each build, add a link, and a monitoring page. Adding to the main page is apparently done by adding the action, but I'm still trying to figure out the rest. And how it all ties in, such as:

1. Does hudson scan for class extending notifier? (I can see no
   references anywhere to the notifier
   class of the monitoring plugin yet
   it must be called somehow since it
   is added to the main page)
2. Does the rootaction class cause the
   URL binding since there also seem to
       be no references to that
   enter code here
3. And how does jelly files get bound
   to the correct page since the
       mapping do not match. Or does
       Jenkins scan for a folder names Bla
       when you have a class called Bla
       extending RootAction?

Does anyone have any pointers, or a place where I can find some decent documentation?

Comment: Try reading [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial). It was last edited on March 29, 2011, so it's pretty recent.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen people use a tutorial I found [here](http://javaadventure.blogspot.com/2008/01/writing-hudson-plug-in-part-1.html) to make plug-ins for Hudson. Jenkins wasn't forked all that long ago, so it should be mostly the same - you'd just need to account for the changed repositories.

Answer (score 1):

Helpful videos:

- [2013-06-15 Jenkins Hackathon -- Introduction zu Plugin Development by Kohsuke Kawaguchi](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PBUkCQ7LW4c) have a lot of information about finding docs, getting started, debugging and testing plugins. Must see video!
- [2012 San Fran JUC: Justin Ryan - Getting To Your Third Plugin](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bmm06tnZuyY) good explain of how to build structure of plugins, what is descriptors and describable.
- http://cleantestcode.wordpress.com/2013/11/03/how-to-write-a-jenkins-plugin-introduction/ - cycle of 4 posts about writing UI-extend plugin.

Comment: The link for Jenkins Hackathon you have provided requires authentication. I have found youtube link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PBUkCQ7LW4c