# Jenkins customize build history view

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I would like to build a jenkins plugin which should customize the Build History view. I want to add a link to each successful job in the build history and perform some action. I also want to know how to access the SCM information for that build run from the plugin.

Can you help me with code snippet or any help? Thanks

Comment: did you write a build history plugin? if so perhaps you could post a link I need someway to manage/filter the displaying of the build history.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/29768722/398670

Answer (score 8):

There is a way to customize the Build History View by implementing [BuildBadgeAction](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/BuildBadgeAction.html) interface of Jenkins.

[Groovy Postbuild Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin) implements and extends the build history view.

Comment: I don't think that lets you actually filter the view, or override the list of jobs displayed though. You can just decorate the jobs.

Answer (score 2):

If you **really** want to write a Jenkins plugin, here is [a link to a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7162492/1178189) that addresses it. Start working on your plugin and then you'll be able to ask more specific questions relating to concrete problems you face. I think that in the present form your question is too vague.

Make sure, however, that writing a plugin is not an overkill for your needs. Chances are that you may be able to do what you need by the 'usual' means. But then again in order to be helped you need to be more specific.